# Problems with multi-threading visual c#

Tags: c#

I'm working on something that login to a linux device with ssh.
Then I want to monitor the connection status every 5 seconds.
I tried to do it with the background worker, but I had many problems with cross-threading.
So I created new threads manually and handled the cross threading with delegation.

But I it's not working very well.
For example during the login the UI stack for couple of seconds until the login is done.

This is the login code I'm using:

```
    private void login_button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        toolStripProgressBar1.Visible = true;
        status.Text = "Connecting...";
        Thread t = new Thread(check_del_login);
        t.IsBackground = true;
        t.Start();
    }
    delegate void del();
    private void check_del_login()
    {
        if (this.InvokeRequired)
        {
            del d = new del(login);
            Invoke(d);
        }
        else
        {
            login();
        }
    }
    private void login()
    {
        ssh = new ssh_login(ip_addr, ssh_username, ssh_password);
        f = new Form3();
        f.sftp(ip_addr, ssh_username, ssh_password);// Send the information to the new form
        try
        {
            ssh.login1();//Connect
            ssh.login2();//Connect
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            log(ex);
        }
        if (!ssh.check_login1() || !ssh.check_login2())
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Could not login by SSH to " + ip_addr);
            return;
        }
        try
        {
            f.login();// Login with sftp
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            log(ex);
        }
        if (!f.check_connection())
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Could not login by web to " + ip_addr);
            return;
        }
        toolStripProgressBar1.Visible = false;// hide the progress bar when the process finishes
        if (ssh.check_login1() && ssh.check_login2() && f.check_connection())
        {
            status.Text = "Connected";
            connection_status_timer.Start();
            status.Text = "Updating interface list...";
            Thread t = new Thread(check_del_update_interface);
            t.IsBackground = true;
            t.Start();
            show_form();
            hide_login();
        }
        else
        {
            status.Text = "Disconnected";
            hide_form();
            show_login();
            comboBox_interface.Items.Clear();
            comboBox_interface.Items.Insert(0, "any");
            connection_status_timer.Stop();
        }
    }
```

I went over all the guides I could find on-line, but I just don't understand what I'm doing wrong.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You're going the wrong way. Separate the thread-code from the ui-code. As much as possible.

Answer (score 3):

Your direct problem is `check_del_login()`  it will always Invoke() the main login()  method. And that means your actual code is being run on the main thread again.

```
private void check_del_login()   // is run on a thread
{
    if (this.InvokeRequired)     // always true
    {
        del d = new del(login);  // so, run login() on Main thread again
        Invoke(d);
    }
    else
    {
        login();
    }
}
```

You should simply eliminate thos method and run `login()` on the thread directly. But then you run into (just the first one):

```
 toolStripProgressBar1.Visible = false;// hide the progress bar when the process finishes
```

this method touches the GUI so it should be Invoked. And you have a lot of similar code.

Best advice: go back to the Backgroundworker and fix your UI issues.